# Filtering a query using an "Array Field" in SQL alchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have got two models coded.

```
class Role(Base):
    __tablename__ = "roles"
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(500), nullable=False)


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    username = Column(String(254), unique=True, nullable=False)
    roles = relationship(Role, secondary=user_roles, backref=backref("users"))
```

One user can have multiple roles, e.g. `roles = [A, B]`.  I have a query containing some users and their roles. I would like to exclude all the users whose roles contains `B`.

I tried to do it in the following way:

```
query = query.filter(~Role.name.contains('B')).all()
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. Is there any method to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the entities at the correct one | many side:

```
# python3.8 | sqlalchemy 1.4
# One user has many roles (or least one)
# role_name is a List[string]
# role_name: ["A", "B"] for example
# The most internal query will query the roles and then apply the join
users = session.query(User)\
    .join(Role)\
    .filter(
        Role.userid == User.id,
        Role.name.in_(role_name)
    )\
    .all()
# Returning all the users related with the roles specified
return users
```

Comment: That does not work unfortunately. I still get people with roles equal to both `A` and `B`. I would like to exclude all users with role `B` :(

Comment: @Hendrra in that case you should use the `not_in`  statement, docs: [sqlAlchemy - Comparator not in](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.PropComparator.not_in) , replace `in_(role_name)` by `not_in(role_name)`, make sure that `role_name` contains the `role.name` that you need to avoid.